# Sharepoint 2013 javascript Add value in calendar list current user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

I have a ParticipantsPickerId (Attendees)  field in my Calendar List in Sharepoint 2013.
How add value current user in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var listName = 'Testcal';

var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;  

var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.TestcalListItem" },
    "Title": 'New caledar item',
    'ParticipantsPickerIdId': userid  //single-valued User field value 
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(taskProperties),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible Update field, not overwriting old records?